# Get Google Page main photo?

Tags: google-places-api

I am using Google Places to render some hotels from a specific area in a website. I was able to get the details like:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=CoQBfAAAAGnd67oCT886cIfOC8m57hGAHyf9saAs8hueRcbguA22mPcazjkk23BWMUOgvrigofuwM1HfRGpLcFtF1WXxv3_n8gb6WgXfaqQFbA0U4_ytSyLyksipx2tjwWU-3EW39ePYtpYhiCwRq9xlNI72Ah4Wv0WytqiJOTF49iTBwCD9EhD1ez5NJDr-pZMI9WagObi3GhQmn9Dum95KN61ZKamJ27wUoJxjvQ&sensor=true&key=[google_key]`

If you see the result, it also has a `url` to [official google page](http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=6218548953562511816).

Is there any way to get the photo of this place from there?

Because the `icon` parameter does not have the image from here but a specific google image which is the same for all lodging types places.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892772

Comment: There is no need for google to provide the image-url, because the owner has granted the usage of the image(and other contents) to google, not to users of the maps-API. So this information would be redundant

Comment: @Dr.Molle Sorry but I don't agree with this. If you are true, then this means we should not access a lot of information which is available trough the API's (for instance place name, place address etc).

Comment: well, usually place-names and addresses are not subject to copyright, images are, text's also may.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Places API does not currently support this feature. If you believe this would be a useful feature you can submit a `Places API - Feature Request' here:

> http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request

Answer (score -1):

Google Places API Photos like Google Maps Photo. It is not Business Photo.